# why is memmove garbling first few bytes

Tags: c, memory, memcpy

I am writing a hobbyOS. I want to copy a small section of memory from 1 spot to another. Somehow my `memmove` function keeps garbling the first few bytes and only the first few bytes.

This is my memmove function:

```
void* memmove(void *dst, const void *src, uint32_t n)
{
  const char *s;
  char *d;

  s = src;
  d = dst;
  if(s < d && s + n > d){
    s += n;
    d += n;
    while(n-- > 0)
      *--d = *--s;
  } else
    while(n-- > 0)
      *d++ = *s++;

  return dst;
}
```

I then call the function like so:

```
char *dest
char *origin    
memmove(dest, origin, 100);
```

When I inspect the memory after (i am using Boschs) I get this odd discrepancy in the first few bytes, everything after is copied as expected:

```
original at 0x502220:
0x0000000000502220 <bogus+       0>:    0x50224468  0x223c6800  0x006a0050

copy at 0x0:
0x0000000000000000 <bogus+       0>:    0x00504460  0x223c6800  0x006a0050
```

As you can see, only the first 4 bytes are garbled. The rest is copied as expected.

What is causing this behavior?

Comment: Did you allocate memory?

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes. `dest` points to a freshly allocated page.

Comment: I tend to bet on compiler optimization that replaces some 8-bit operations with 32-bit operations.

Comment: Code looks good, pretty much identical to [what I wrote for PDCLib](https://bitbucket.org/pdclib/pdclib/src/a82b02d0c7d4ed633b97f2a7639d9a10b1c92ec8/functions/string/memmove.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), which tests OK. (You're welcome to use PDCLib for your hobby OS, in parts or as a whole. It's been written for that very purpose.) I suspect an error in your testing, really.

Comment: Are you really moving to address 0 ? If you really are, maybe you have something else writing to a null pointer ?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]! As given, your pointers are **not** initialised. And `uint32_t` is the wrong type for the size. If you use the standard name, you should use the correct types. Also make sure _your_ function is really called.

Comment: @ElderBug: A _null pointer_ is not the same as address 0.

Comment: @Olaf No sane compiler would make a null pointer not 0. The C standard requires that `(char*)0` converts to a null pointer.

Comment: It would be best if you indicated in the question that `dest` and `origin` are properly initialized somehow. As it stands, they could be misread as uninitialized variables.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I think your answer should remain undeleted, a disclaimer "this is wrong but the comments are good" should suffice to discourage downvotes. Can't really *answer* this question, as the problem seems to be in the testing code, not the `memmove` implementation (other than that he *should* be using **`unsigned char`** instead of `char`).

Comment: @ElderBug: While unlikely, this is implementation defined and very well possible. It has nothing to do with the compiler, but the ABI and the underlying hardware. OP does not state which hardware, CPU, etc. Unless more information is given, we have to strictly follow the standard. And this even allows for more than one encoding to be interpreted as a _null pointer_.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: That' why we first should ask for a [mcve]. Until then any answer is just speculation and leads to unnecessary discussion.

Answer (score 3):

1. Following is UB.  Cannot reliably compare with `< <= >= >` 2 pointers that are not of the same array, object.

   ```
   if(s < d && s + n > d){
   ```

> When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the address space of the objects pointed to. If two pointers to object types both point to the same object,...  If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object, ... All pointers to members of the same union object ...  **In all other cases, the behavior is undefined.**
>   C11dr §6.5.8 5 Relational operators

2. It is more canonical to use `size_t n` rather than `uint32_t n`.
3. In the below usage, both `dest, src` are not initialized [@Bathsheba delted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270518/2410359).  Based on user info, it appear code attempted to write to address 0.  Likely the system prevents that.  But it is UB using uninitialized pointers.

   ```
   char *dest
   char *origin    
   memmove(dest, origin, 100);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the `memmove` was succeeding without faults, but a concurrent (faulty) process was thrashing the first 4 bytes. I should have tested that better.

Thank you for all your answers.